# How do I connect to my VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04LTS from the host's public IP(or domain name)?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

I've been having a hard time with this. It's probably been 3 days now...

Anyway,

- I've set up my virtualbox on Windows7 with a bridged adapter (eth0).
- Installed LAMP server and it works.
- I can access my site from its' static IP on my host.
- I forwarded port 80 to the static IP of my virtualbox server on my router (not sure if I did this correctly?)
- Checked if the port 80 was open on the canyouseeme site and it was not. My ISP does NOT block port 80 (comcast). I think the problem
  here is just that nothing is listening for port 80 on my host?

What am I missing? Shouldn't I be able to connect to my site via public/external I.P. because I forwarded port 80 (and 443) to the static IP of my serving virtual machine? Do I need something to listen for port 80 on my host?

Thanks in advance for any help. It is much appreciated..!

Comment: sounds as if port forwarding is not configured properly on your router.

Comment: I go to forwarding -> create IPv4 -> type in:
Local IP: 192.168.0.101 (my server),
Local Start Port: 80,
Local End Port: 80,
External IP: I type in to google "whats my ip" to get this IP,
External Start Port: 80,
External End Port: 80,
Protocol: BOTH UDP + TCP,
Enabled: Check.
Is this correct?